# Left or Right swipe not working in appium for android application

Tags: java, android, appium

I'm trying to swipe right to left from the first content(there is no content at left hand side) or Left to Right So far I'm using below, but it's not working.

```
public void swipeRightToLeft() {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        HashMap<String, Double> swipeObject = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        swipeObject.put("startX", 0.9);
        swipeObject.put("startY", 0.5);
        swipeObject.put("endX", 0.01);
        swipeObject.put("endY", 0.5);
        swipeObject.put("duration", 3.0);
        js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", swipeObject);
}

public void swipeLeftToRight() {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        HashMap<String, Double> swipeObject = new HashMap<String, Double>();
        swipeObject.put("startX", 0.01);
        swipeObject.put("startY", 0.5);
        swipeObject.put("endX", 0.9);
        swipeObject.put("endY", 0.6);
        swipeObject.put("duration", 3.0);
        js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", swipeObject);
}
```

Error log: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Not yet implemented. Please help us: http://appium.io/get-involved.html1 (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

I'm using appium java-client 4.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ans found on Appium discussion: https://discuss.appium.io/t/left-or-right-swipe-not-working-in-appium-for-android-app/14515/4

```
public static void swipeHorizontal(AppiumDriver driver, double startPercentage, double finalPercentage, double anchorPercentage, int duration) throws Exception {
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int anchor = (int) (size.height * anchorPercentage);
    int startPoint = (int) (size.width * startPercentage);
    int endPoint = (int) (size.width * finalPercentage);
    new TouchAction(driver).press(startPoint, anchor).waitAction(duration).moveTo(endPoint, anchor).release().perform();
}
```

Call it By: `swipeHorizontal(driver,0.9,0.01,0.5,3000);`